# Paypal Integration with php not forwarding to paypal

Tags: php, paypal, payment

I am trying to integrate `paypal` into a pet adoption website that I am building. However I had a basic code working, and when I built around it, it stopped forwarding to the `paypal` website to make the payment.

This is the page that is supposed to start and finish the charge and then save the information to the database.

I'm also not completely sure how to grab the information coming back to the website from `paypal` to save the transaction data.

the code i have to make the sale :

```
$product = $dogname;
$price = $deposit;
$shipping = 0.00;

$total = $price + $shipping;

$payer = new Payer();
$payer ->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

$item = new Item();
$item -> setName($product)
->setCurrency('USD')
->setQuantity(1)
->setPrice($price);
$itemList = new ItemList();
$itemList ->setItems([$item]);

$details = new Details();
$details ->setShipping($shipping)
->setSubtotal($price);

$amount = new Amount();
$amount->setCurrency('USD')
->setTotal($total)
->setDetails($details);

$transaction = new Transaction();
$transaction->setAmount($amount)
->setItemList($itemlist)
->setDescription("Deposit for ". $dogname);
$redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
$redirectUrls->setReturnUrl(SITE_URL . "/adoption.php?success=TRUE")
->setCancelUrl(SITE_URL . "/adoption.php?success=FALSE");

$payment = new Payment();
$payment->setIntent('sale')
->setPayer($payer)
->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)
->setTransactions([$transaction]);
try{
$payment ->create($paypal);
} catch(Exception $e){
die($e);
}
$approvalUrl = $payment->getApprovalLink();
?>
<script>
setTimeout(function(){
window.location = "<?php echo $approvalUrl; ?>";
}, 100);
</script>
<?php
}
```

And then to process the sale on my end

```
$paymentId = $_GET['paymentId'];
$payerId = $_GET['PayerID'];

$payment = Payment::get($paymentId, $paypal);
$execute = new PaymentExecution();
$execute->setPayerId($payerId);
try{
$result = $payment->execute($execute, $paypal);
?>
<script>
setTimeout(function(){
window.location = "/adoption.php?payment=success";
}, 100);
</script>
<?php

}catch(Exception $e){
$data = json_decode($e->getData());
var_dump($data->message);
}

}else{
die();
}
echo "Payment Made";
```

I will also be charging a 2.5 % processing fee for our service and was also trying to figure out how to send that to paypal as well.

thanks in advance for the help, I've been looking on `youtube` and `stackoverflow` but cant seem to figure out what the issue is.

Comment: **Too much code**. You need to do a better job of troubleshooting this yourself. We are *not* debuggers. You need **isolate the problem** and debug from there. If you're stuck provide a **clear explanation of what isn't working** with a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading **[ask]** a good question and **[the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)**. Also, be sure to take the **[tour]** and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/)**.

Comment: I have shortened the code down to simply the code that has to do with the transaction itself. Instead of the whole page. 

It stopped working when I tried to add in a processing fee. But I reverted it back and still doesn't work...

Comment: Again I made some changes to shorten the code. I hope someone can help me figure this out... Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue i was having with the PayPal integration. The form wasn't sending the information over to be submitted to paypal. :'(